# How do I style a JavaFX TextField to look like an iOS one?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, styling

How do I style a JavaFX `TextField` to look like an iOS one?

[image]

I want to have the non-rounded corners, insets/padding, the colors, and the prompt text(including the font).

Comment: Are you refering to the `promtText`, the non-rounded corners or something else?

Comment: @fabian I want to have the non-rounded corners, insets/padding, the colors, and the prompt text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the TextField appearance to match the iOS using the CSS rules below :

```
#ios-field {
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-border-color : #D7D6DC;
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 4 7 4 15 ;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: derive(-fx-control-inner-background,-30%);
}

#ios-field:focused {
    -fx-border-color : #D7D6DC;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, -1.4, 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 4 7 4 15 ;
}
```

I believe the CSS rules are self-explanatory and it will be easy for you to make changes. 
I used the #D7D6DC color as a border color to match the one in your image also the -fx-background-insets are the default values used in modenas.css

Result :

[image]

P.S 
I can't see if the border (LEFT and RIGHT) in your image exists in case you only want to display the upper and bottom border you can do that as well by `-fx-border-width : 1 0 1 0;`. In addition for font size and family you can use `-fx-font-size` and `-fx-font-family`. The font used for iOS is [San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/).

Comment: @abc Sadly I dont. You will need to search the web to find the iOS version you like and then to find the font for the specific control. In case you are wondering how to change font you can do that by `-fx-font-size` and `-fx-font-family` rules.

Comment: Thanks, the font seems to be [San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/)